# Update JSON depending upon User Input

Tags: python, json

I want to create Database using JSON based on inputs of user. I have written this code, but it replaces the whole file with new data and doesn't update the existing JSON file.

The file database.json gives an output as

```
{"Employee ID": "ID2", "Employee Name": "Friendrich", "Domain": "Engineering", "Employee Type": "Permanent", "Start Date": "01.02.2020", "End Date": "28.02.2021"}
```

```
import json


s_id = input('employeeID')
s_name = input('employeeName')
s_domain = input('domain')
s_type = input('employeeType')
s_from = input('start-date')
s_until = input('end-date')

database = {
        'Employee ID' : s_id,
        'Employee Name' : s_name,
        'Domain' : s_domain,
        'Employee Type' : s_type,
        'Start Date' : s_from,
        'End Date' : s_until
        }

with open('database.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

data.update(database)

with open('database.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(database, json_file)
```

With new input the json file should add the data to the existing file.

So the output should be

```
{"Employee ID": "new ID", "Employee Name": "input name", "Domain": "input domain", "Employee Type": "input type", "Start Date": "input date", "End Date": "input date"}, {"Employee ID": "ID2", "Employee Name": "Friendrich", "Domain": "Engineering", "Employee Type": "Permanent", "Start Date": "01.02.2020", "End Date": "28.02.2021"},
```

I am creating this database in order to find all employee with certain filter. Lets say all Employees with domain Engineering. Is it good practice to use JSON as a database?

Comment: I'd look at using `sqlite3` if you want a lightweight DB instead of reinventing it with JSON.

Comment: Okay I would check that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You truncate the file each time you save the data.
Use "**a**" and not "**w**" as open mode.

See https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#open

Replace

```
with open('database.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(database, json_file)
```

with

```
with open('database.json', 'a') as json_file:
    json.dump(database, json_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question, it is easier to use sqlite3 (plus python) to update a database. Check it out!